# data table in a c# Asp.Net data set contains columns from other data tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datatable, dataset

I am working on an old Asp.Net Webform project that uses DataSet.xsd witch includes few data tables.  When I try to fill the Data Table there is a strange problem like mixing up columns of two different Data Tables that I can not find the reason.
This is a picture of the Data Table that I am trying to fill:

[image]

and this is a picture of my .xsd file:

[image]

as you see in these pictures, there are three columns in the 'DataTableVehichlePresence' that appear in 'DataTableVp' at run time when I try to fill it!!! I am so confused! I can not understand what is happening on run time and how I can fix the issue. 
I got really stuck and need your help.

Comment: Check  of the procedure return that columna, if columns are on data, check autogenerate columns is turn off

Comment: Thank you for your comment  Henoc. Your're right! database was returning those columns, however now that I changed my database view to not return them, I encountered another error that is " Invalid column name 'PlateAlfabet' " on this line:
    sd.Fill(ds.Tables["DataTableVP"]);

Comment: probably the name of the column in your view is written differently, check the name.

I will generate an answer so that you can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check of the procedure return that column, if columns are on data, check autogenerate columns is turn off, or change the procedure.